# Can't solve this Query on checkbox - VB.net MYSQL Query

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, mysql-workbench

When check the science checkbox . The Science will show in a DataGridView but when i check the Reading and Science, the two subject is can't show on the DataGridView. What is the best way(code) to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

```
`Public com As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
 Public da As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter
 Public dr As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader
 Public dt As New DataTable
 Public dt2 As New DataTable
 Public ds As DataSet
 Dim strSQL As String
 Dim strSQL2 As String

 Private Sub gbsubject_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles gbsubject.Enter

 Dim SDA As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter
 Dim dbDataSet As New DataTable
 Dim bSource As New BindingSource

 If cbxscience.Checked = True Then

        con.Close()
        con.Open()

        strSQL2 = "SELECT subject_tbl.subject, lessonplan_tbl.lessontitle, kind_tbl.kind FROM kind_tbl INNER JOIN(lessonplan_tbl INNER JOIN(subject_tbl INNER JOIN skul_tbl ON subject_tbl.subjectID = skul_tbl.subjectID) ON lessonplan_tbl.lessonplanID = skul_tbl.lessonplanID) ON kind_tbl.kindID = skul_tbl.kindID WHERE subject_tbl.subject = '" & "SCIENCE" & "'"

        dgvlessonplan.AutoSizeRowsMode = _
   DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None


        com = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(strSQL2, con)
        SDA.SelectCommand = com
        SDA.Fill(dbDataSet)
        bSource.DataSource = dbDataSet
        dgvlessonplan.DataSource = bSource
        SDA.Update(dbDataSet)
        con.Close()

    End If

    If cbxreading.Checked And cbxscience.Checked Then

        con.Close()
        con.Open()

        strSQL2 = "SELECT subject_tbl.subject, lessonplan_tbl.lessontitle, kind_tbl.kind FROM kind_tbl INNER JOIN(lessonplan_tbl INNER JOIN(subject_tbl INNER JOIN skul_tbl ON subject_tbl.subjectID = skul_tbl.subjectID) ON lessonplan_tbl.lessonplanID = skul_tbl.lessonplanID) ON kind_tbl.kindID = skul_tbl.kindID WHERE subject_tbl.subject = '" & "READING" & "' and subject_tbl.subject = '" & "SCIENCE" & "'"

        dgvlessonplan.AutoSizeRowsMode = _
   DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None


        com = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(strSQL2, con)
        SDA.SelectCommand = com
        SDA.Fill(dbDataSet)
        bSource.DataSource = dbDataSet
        dgvlessonplan.DataSource = bSource
        SDA.Update(dbDataSet)
        con.Close()

    End If`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an `OR` not an `AND` in your `strSQL2` variable.

So, change this:

```
 strSQL2 = "SELECT subject_tbl.subject, lessonplan_tbl.lessontitle, kind_tbl.kind FROM kind_tbl INNER JOIN(lessonplan_tbl INNER JOIN(subject_tbl INNER JOIN skul_tbl ON subject_tbl.subjectID = skul_tbl.subjectID) ON lessonplan_tbl.lessonplanID = skul_tbl.lessonplanID) ON kind_tbl.kindID = skul_tbl.kindID WHERE subject_tbl.subject = '" & "READING" & "' and subject_tbl.subject = '" & "SCIENCE" & "'"
```

to this:

```
 strSQL2 = "SELECT subject_tbl.subject, lessonplan_tbl.lessontitle, kind_tbl.kind FROM kind_tbl INNER JOIN(lessonplan_tbl INNER JOIN(subject_tbl INNER JOIN skul_tbl ON subject_tbl.subjectID = skul_tbl.subjectID) ON lessonplan_tbl.lessonplanID = skul_tbl.lessonplanID) ON kind_tbl.kindID = skul_tbl.kindID WHERE subject_tbl.subject = 'READING' OR subject_tbl.subject = 'SCIENCE'"
```